# Discord.netでローカルの音楽を再生する方法

Tags: c#, discord

Discord.Netにて、BotをVCに接続し、ローカルにおいてある音楽を再生する方法を探しております。

```
var ffmpeg = Process.Start(Process);
await channel.ConnectAsync();
using (var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
using (var discord = IAudioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
{
  try { await output.CopyToAsync(discord); }
  finally { await discord.FlushAsync(); }
}
```

上のコードの通りffmpegで変換した(変換処理コードは省略しました)mp3をdiscordに流そうと試行錯誤しているのですが、

```
CS0120 'IAudioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication, int?, int, int)' で、オブジェクト参照が必要です
```

と表示され、デバッグすらできません...

また、上のコードでConnectAsyncした後、何も動作せずタイムアウトしてVCから切断してしまう問題も発生してしまっています。そちらも併せて解決方法をご教授いただけませんでしょうか?

Comment: この辺の記事が類似の話題を扱ってそうです。[Streaming MP3 to Discord.net 2.0 - audio is super-fast (chipmunk). Ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56026466/9014308), [Discord.net Bot. MusicBot capability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55787100/9014308), [discord-music-bot](https://github.com/topics/discord-music-bot?l=c%23), [mrousavy/DiscordMusicBot](https://github.com/mrousavy/DiscordMusicBot), [luther38/DiscordMusicBot](https://github.com/luther38/DiscordMusicBot), [DiscordのBotでボイスチャンネルに音楽を流す](https://qiita.com/Tachibana446/items/82a4f848762da79c6d8b)

Comment: なんやかんや有りましてIAudioClientをWaveFormatConversionStreamにしましたところ、`Stream does not support writing.`が返されるようになってしまいました.....(上のリンク達を確認し、すべて実施しましたが私の技術では既存のコードを書き換えることに失敗しました。)

Comment: The process cannot access the file '(ファイルパス)' because it is being used by another process.も出てくるようになってきました.....

Comment: こちらの記事の方が直接的かもしれません。[How to play music from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52040781/9014308), [Inquisition/Inquisition.Core.Modules/AudioModule.cs](https://github.com/TheKrystalShip/Inquisition/blob/master/Inquisition.Core.Modules/AudioModule.cs), [Inquisition/Inquisition.Services/AudioService.cs](https://github.com/TheKrystalShip/Inquisition/blob/master/Inquisition.Services/AudioService.cs)

Comment: すべてのリンクを踏み、コードを書いていきましたが最終的にはエラーまつりでした....最終的になにもいじれず、上のコードの一部改変(IAudioClientをWaveFormat~~)で終わってしまい、エラーコードは`Stream does not support writing.`のままでした。検索方法が悪いのは理解しているのですが、どの様に検索してもヒントにはなりませんでした...

Comment: そうすると残念ながら経験者が回答してくれるのを待つしか無いですね。